# Getting Raw contact id from id

Tags: android

The following code worked perfectly two days ago, but suddenly - I don't what happened - the code behaves abnormally, it gives output as ID and `RawId` were same. For example:

```
Id =356
RawId = 356
```

I tried my best to know what is the matter, unsuccessfuly. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
String projection[]=new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
                      String where=ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID+"=?";
                      String selectionArgs[]=new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
                      CursorLoader cLoader=new CursorLoader(this,ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,projection,where,selectionArgs,null);
                      Cursor c=cLoader.loadInBackground();
                      c.moveToFirst();
                      rawContactID=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Id = "+id+" \nRaw id = "+rawContactID,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: some body ,please response to the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public int getRawContactId(int contactId) {
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)};
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    c.moveToNext();
    int rawContactId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
    return rawContactId;
}
```